# To display variables of IReport in chart of IReport

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I have some FIELDS (IReport), which I get from database by SQL-Statements. 
Then I do some calculations and save the results in VARIABLES of IReport.

So, now I would like to display these variables in a chart.

How can I do it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Variables the same way that you use Field in the jrxml template.  Just put/use the variable on the report the same way you would a field.

If you want details on how to make some particular chart or display could you give some more info on that?